# The mapDispatchToProps feedback can not update mapStateToProps immediately

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

When using redux to control login form, I encounter some weird problem

the main code below:

```
import ...

class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    ...
  }
  componentWillUnmount(){
    clearTimeout(this.timeoutHandle);
  }
  handleName(evt) {
    this.setState({name: evt.target.value})
  }
  handlePwd(evt) {
    this.setState({pwd: evt.target.value})
  }
  handleLogin(evt) {
    const { name, pwd } = this.state
    const { errcode } = this.props.loginItems
    const { fetchLogin } = this.props
    let login = {
      name: name,
      pwd: pwd
    }
    fetchLogin(login)
    console.log(errcode)                                 <------ this line
    errcode === 0 && (
      this.timeoutHandle = setTimeout(() => {
        this.loginSuccess()
      }, 1000)
    )
  }
  loginSuccess() {
    ...
  }
  render() {
    const { errcode, errmsg } = this.props.loginItems
    const { name, pwd } = this.state
    return (
      <FlexContainerCenterColumn>
        <LoginInput
          onChange={this.handleName}
          value={name}>
        </LoginInput>
        <LoginInput
          type="password"
          onChange={this.handlePwd}
          value={pwd}>
        </LoginInput>
        <SubmitButton
          ...
          onClick={this.handleLogin}>
          Login
        </SubmitButton>
        <LoginFoot>
          {errcode === 1 && ...}
          {errcode === 0 && ...}
        </LoginFoot>
      </FlexContainerCenterColumn>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  (state) => ({
    loginItems: state.login.loginItems
  }),
  {changeRoute, fetchLogin}
)(withRouter(LoginForm))
```

The fetchLogin is a post method to get feedback from server

if login success:

```
loginItems:{
  errcode: 0,
  errmsg: ''
}
```

and login fail:

```
loginItems:{
  errcode: 1,
  errmsg: 'login failure'
}
```

This form is a controlled component

First login success, the `console.log(errcode)` return `1`, then login again it returns `0`.

How should I get the correct return `0` at first login success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `fetchLogin`, you seem to be updating the redux store, and the store update doesn't happen immediately, so `errorcode` isn't correct immediately after you dispatch the action

You need to implement the test logic on errorcode in `componentDidUpdate (In view of version 16.3.0, Previously you would use componentWillReceiveProps)` method

```
class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    ...
  }
  componentWillUnmount(){
    clearTimeout(this.timeoutHandle);
  }
  handleName(evt) {
    this.setState({name: evt.target.value})
  }
  handlePwd(evt) {
    this.setState({pwd: evt.target.value})
  }
  handleLogin(evt) {
    const { name, pwd } = this.state
    const { fetchLogin } = this.props
    let login = {
      name: name,
      pwd: pwd
    }
    fetchLogin(login)
  }
  loginSuccess() {
    ...
  }
   componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
     const {errorcode: prevErrorcode } = prevProps.loginItems;
     const {errorcode } = prevProps.loginItems;
     if(errorcode !== prevErrorcode) {
       errcode === 0 && (
          this.timeoutHandle = setTimeout(() => {
             this.loginSuccess()
          }, 1000)
       )
    }

  }
  render() {
    const { errcode, errmsg } = this.props.loginItems
    const { name, pwd } = this.state
    return (
      <FlexContainerCenterColumn>
        <LoginInput
          onChange={this.handleName}
          value={name}>
        </LoginInput>
        <LoginInput
          type="password"
          onChange={this.handlePwd}
          value={pwd}>
        </LoginInput>
        <SubmitButton
          ...
          onClick={this.handleLogin}>
          Login
        </SubmitButton>
        <LoginFoot>
          {errcode === 1 && ...}
          {errcode === 0 && ...}
        </LoginFoot>
      </FlexContainerCenterColumn>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  (state) => ({
    loginItems: state.login.loginItems
  }),
  {changeRoute, fetchLogin}
)(withRouter(LoginForm))
```

Comment: It seems the mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps method not update the redux store at the same time

Comment: After an action is dispatched, the store gets updated and then mapStateToProps is called again

Comment: When dispatch a mapDispatchToProps method, the state of mapStateToProps is updated before render the component or after render the component?

Comment: In my main code, the `{errcode === 0 && ...}` is rendered at first login success, but the `console.log(errcode)` is still return `1`

Comment: where exactly, do you write the console.log

Comment: At handleLogin method

Comment: As I said, console.log(errocode) won't give you the correct result, since the state gets updated later and before that console.log is executed. if you login in componentDidUpdate or render, you will get the correct result.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer is correct exactly, but I can not understand why the mapDispatchToProps not update mapStateToProps immediately

Comment: Can you ask a separate question for `why the mapDispatchToProps not update mapStateToProps immediately`

Comment: I change the title yet.

Comment: Please ask a separate question for it since your original question did not have this in its scope